# GridView not taking DDL.SelectedValue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, datagridview

I have a DDL which is used to filter projects on categories. And it works perfect. I store the selected value into a session like this:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Categorie") = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

And recall it on Page_Load like this:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Cookie()

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then           
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Categorie")
        End If
    End Sub
```

And the DDL **displays** the value on the DLL it self, but its not binding it to the GridView.

You are also allowed to filter it on txtboxes, and I save values exactly the same way:

```
Protected Sub txtKlant_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Klant") = txtKlant.Text
End Sub
```

And also call them on page_Load however Those values active inmediatly and display the data filterd on the *Klant* (Customer)

My whole code:

***PageLoad***

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Cookie()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then           
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Categorie")
        txtKlant.Text = Session("Klant")
        txtWebsite.Text = Session("Website")
        txtTitel.Text = Session("Titel")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

***Sessions***

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Categorie") = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
End Sub

Protected Sub txtKlant_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Klant") = txtKlant.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub txtWebsite_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Website") = txtWebsite.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub txtTitel_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Titel") = txtTitel.Text
End Sub
```

> I dont get any error. The filtering does work, but when I go to a
>   other page, press the back button it doesnt keep the selected value of
>   the session. So the selection on categories is lost. But it does keep the value's of the 
>   textboxes which are handled the same way

***/EDIT//***

**GridView:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" 
        gridlines="None"
        cellpadding="15"
        width="980px"   
        ItemStyle-backcolor="#ebecf0"
        AlternatingItemStyle-backcolor="#ebecf0" 
        AllowPaging="True" 
        PageSize="4" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        datasourceid="SqlDataSource2"
        > 

//BOUNDED ITEMS//

</GridView>
```

**The SQLDATASOURCE**

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_Project] INNER JOIN tbl_Cat      ON tbl_Project.CatID = tbl_Cat.Cat_ID 
INNER JOIN tbl_Klant    ON tbl_Project.KlantID = tbl_Klant.Klant_ID 
WHERE (([Titel] LIKE '%' + @Titel + '%') 
AND  ([CatID] = CASE WHEN @CatID = -1 THEN [CatID] ELSE @CatID END) AND ([Bedrijf] LIKE '%' + @Bedrijf + '%') 
AND ([Website] LIKE '%' + @Website + '%'))"  

deletecommand="DELETE FROM [tbl_Project] WHERE [ID] = @original_ID" 
OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" >

<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>


<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTitel" DefaultValue="*" Name="Titel" 
    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />

    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtKlant" DefaultValue="*" Name="Bedrijf" 
    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />


    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtWebsite" DefaultValue="*" Name="Website" 
    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />

    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="1" 
    Name="CatID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32"                      ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
```

Comment: How do you mean? It works for the textboxes, what is different? Alla textChanged events are handled and .SelectedIndexChanged is also handled

Comment: Nothing, I dont get any error. The filtering does work, but when I go to a other page, press the back button it doesnt keep the selected value of the session. So the selection on categories is lost. @Yvette no Web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very easy fix. This morning I had a clear moment. Fixed as following:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Cookie()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then           
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Categorie")
        txtKlant.Text = Session("Klant")
        txtWebsite.Text = Session("Website")
        txtTitel.Text = Session("Titel")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

This was my first pageload which dindt work.

This is my new one, which works perfect.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Cookie()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Categorie")
        If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Categorie") = True Then
            GridView1.DataBind()

            txtKlant.Text = Session("Klant")
            txtWebsite.Text = Session("Website")
            txtTitel.Text = Session("Titel")
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see in your code where you have created an event handler for databind.

I've taken some examples from MSDN, to show the steps you need.

```
Function CreateDataSource() As ICollection

  'put your data source in here

End Function 'CreateDataSource


'Declaration
Public Event ItemDataBound As DataGridItemEventHandler

    Sub Item_Bound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs)

    Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " " & e.Item.ItemIndex
End Sub 'Item_Bound 


  Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     ' Manually register the event-handling method for the  
     ' ItemDataBound event of the DataGrid control.
     AddHandler ItemsGrid.ItemDataBound, AddressOf Item_Bound

     ' Load sample data only once, when the page is first loaded.
     If Not IsPostBack Then

        ItemsGrid.DataSource = CreateDataSource()
        ItemsGrid.DataBind()

     End If

  End Sub
```

I suggest you check out this link, it is too detailed to reiterate here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx

If this doesn't solve your issue, please let me know.